# Windows batch script to print error message if port in use

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos, port

I'm trying to write a batch script that errors if port 1099 is already in use.

Unfortunately I have to write it in a DOS batch script (I cannot install anything).

I know that I can print the PID of the process hogging port 1099 manually:

```
netstat -aon | findstr ":1099"
```

But I want to be able to run that command in a batch script and exit the script with an error message if that command has any output.

I suppose at a push I could redirect the output to a temporary file and test the size of it but that seems really hacky...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 netstat -an | FINDSTR ":1099" | FINDSTR LISTENING && ECHO Port is in use && EXIT 1
```

You can use `&&` in a batch script to run a command only if the previous command was successful (based on its exit code/`ERRORLEVEL`).  This allows you to display a message and exit only if the string you are looking for is found in the output of netstat.

Also, you want to explicitly look for `LISTENING` ports.

`FINDSTR` supports regular expressions so you can also do the following to shorten the command line:

```
netstat -an | findstr /RC:":1099 .*LISTENING" && ECHO Port is in use && EXIT 1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I just tested it and it works perfectly.
And you also noted the "o" switch was redundant, bonus ;)